# Intuition behind modeling it as a BFS

Tags: c++, queue, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve this question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/description/):

> Given a digit string, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent.  The mappings between the numbers and characters is like the telephone keypad.  So: 
>  
>   2 <-> abc, 
>   3 <-> def, 
>   4 <-> ghi, 
>   and so on...
>
> **Input**: "23"; 
>   **Output**: ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"].

The highly upvoted solution is like below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        std::vector< string > vec;
        if(digits.length()==0)
            return vec;

        std::queue< std::string > ans;
        std::string mapping[]={"0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};

        ans.push("");
        for(int i=0; i<digits.length(); i++)
        {
            int x = (digits[i]-'0');
            while(ans.front().length()==i)
            {
                std::string t=ans.front();
                ans.pop();
                for(int j=0; j<mapping[x].length(); j++)
                {
                    ans.push(t+mapping[x][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        std::string val;
        int size=ans.size();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            val=ans.front();
            ans.pop();
            vec.push_back(val);
        }
        return vec;
    }
};
```

I had the following questions:

1. What is the intuition behind modeling this as a BFS question?  The way *I* thought about it, I would have two vectors, one holding `a`,`b` and `c` as elements (all mapped to `2`) and the other holding `d`, `e` and `f` as elements (all mapped to `3`) and then simply use loops to combine the elements as `ad`,`ae`, etc.  But this is obviously inefficient.  So how is BFS applicable and help here?
2. What exactly is going on, in the condition in the while loop - `ans.front().length()==i` - logically, why is the induction variable `i` being compared with the length of values in the queue?

Thanks!

Comment: `i` is not an `iterator`. It's an `int`.

Comment: @Fureeish, that is why I use the word _variable_ with iterator.  I mean to say, _the variable used for iteration_.  I know the difference. :)

Comment: @Umedh Singh Bundela - the proper name for `i` would be "induction variable".

Comment: @JesperJuhl, edited.  Thank you.

Comment: Then I see nothing incomprehensible with how an `int` is being compared to `.length()`, which is of a type `size_t`

Comment: @Fureeish, I am talking about the logic (and reason) for this comparison - not the syntactical accuracy.  And I believe my point 2 is pretty explanatory about it.  I still edited it though.  Thank you.

Comment: It's not so much that (1) is inefficient, it's that it won't work for arbitrarily long `digits`. You need two nested loops for `digits.length() == 2`, three nested loops for `digits.length() == 3` - but what are you going to do when you don't know the length of the string in advance?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yes, I agree.  And, what is the intuition behind modeling it as a BFS?  I mean, how is it like a graph?

Comment: Imagine a tree where each node `S` at level `k` is a possible combination for the prefix of `digits` of length `k`, and its children are possible combinations for prefix of length `k+1` that start with `S`. The program you show traverses this tree. It doesn't keep the whole tree in memory though - only the current level and the next level.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, could you please elaborate?

Comment: You have a root node that's an empty string. Its children are nodes "a", "b" and "c" - each produced by extending that empty string by one possible translation of `digits[0]`. Node "a" has children "ad", "ae", "af"; node "b" has children "bd", "be", "bf"; and so on - once again, child nodes are expansions of the parent node by one possible translation of `digits[1]`. And so on. The program traverses this tree in a breadth-first manner, building parts of it on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the intuition behind modeling this as a BFS

This is not really a BFS: the authors use a queue for no good reason - they could as well use two vectors - one for the previous generation of strings, and one for the current generation. This would free them from having to check the length of the item at the front of the queue, i.e. `ans.front().length()==i`: they would be abe to write `while (!priorGen.empty()) ...`

> What exactly is going on, in the condition in the while loop ...

The algorithm produces strings by "generations", adding a new character to the end of each string from the prior "generation."

- Generation zero is a single empty string
- Generation `x` is produced from generation `x-1` by appending one of the possible representations of the corresponding digit to the end of each string in generation `x-1`

The queue contains strings from two generations - the prior one, and the current one. Strings from the current generation are longer by one character than strings from the prior generation. Loop condition ensures that the loop continues until we run out of string in the prior generation.

Here is the modified code that uses two separate "generation" vectors instead of a single queue, with the remaining parts of the code kept in place:

```
vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
    string mapping[]={"0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};
    vector<string> priorGen {""};
    vector<string> currentGen;
    if (!digits.size()) return currentGen;
    for(int i=0 ; i < digits.length() ; i++) {
        int x = (digits[i]-'0');
        while(!priorGen.empty()) {
            string t = priorGen.back();
            priorGen.pop_back();
            for(int j=0 ; j < mapping[x].length() ; j++) {
                currentGen.push_back(t+mapping[x][j]);
            }
        }
        swap(priorGen, currentGen);
    }
    return priorGen;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  But if I correctly understand what Igor says in the comments, would it work when we don't know the length of the string in advance?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela It would work exactly the same. Instead of adding the new elements to the current queue/vector, you add them to a new one (that you create/clear before the `while` loop), and after the `while` loop you swap the two queue. Unless you care about the ordering of the output strings, using a queue instead of a simple vector is useless here (with a queue you get output strings in alphabetical order).

Comment: Nice explanation.  Thank you.  Merry Christmas and Happy New Year! :)